# Upload image to PHP server with JSonParser

Tags: php, android, image-uploading

I am trying to upload image with my JSONParser class.**Here is class:**

```
    public class JSONParser {

    String charset = "UTF-8";
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    DataOutputStream wr;
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    URL urlObj;
    JSONObject jObj = null;
    StringBuilder sbParams;
    String paramsString;

    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(final Context context,String url, String method,
                                      HashMap<String, String> params) {

        sbParams = new StringBuilder();
        int i = 0;
        for (String key : params.keySet()) {
            try {
                if (i != 0){
                    sbParams.append("&");
                }
                sbParams.append(key).append("=")
                        .append(URLEncoder.encode(params.get(key), charset));

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            i++;
        }

        if (method.equals("POST")) {
            // request method is POST
            try {
                urlObj = new URL(url);

                conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();

                conn.setDoOutput(true);

                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

                conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);


                conn.setReadTimeout(10*1000);//orijinal 10000

                conn.setConnectTimeout(15*1000);//orijinal 15000

                conn.connect();

                paramsString = sbParams.toString();

                wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                wr.writeBytes(paramsString);
                wr.flush();
                wr.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else if(method.equals("GET")){
            // request method is GET

            if (sbParams.length() != 0) {
                url += "?" + sbParams.toString();
            }

            try {
                urlObj = new URL(url);

                conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();

                conn.setDoOutput(false);

                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

                conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);

                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);

                conn.connect();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                MyMethods.makeToastInAsync(context,context.getResources().getString(R.string.connProblem),Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        try {
            //Receive the response from the server
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line);
            }

            Log.d("JSON Parser", "result: " + result.toString());

        } catch (IOException e) {

            MyMethods.makeToastInAsync(context,context.getResources().getString(R.string.connProblem),Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        conn.disconnect();

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(result.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON Object
        return jObj;
    }
}
```

**Async part of SendImage class:**

```
protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

        try {

            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, byteArrayOutputStream);
            String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);

            Log.d("Send Image", encodedImage);


            HashMap<String, String> dataTosend = new HashMap<>();
            dataTosend.put("image", encodedImage);
            dataTosend.put("name", sharedPreferences.getString("username", ""));

            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(SendImage.this,
                    UPLOAD_IMAGE_URL, "POST", dataTosend);

            if (json != null) {
                Log.d("JSON result", json.toString());

                return json;
            }


        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

So, as you see, first i compress the image and encode with base64 and return String to send with JSONParser.

The problem is, i can send image that not so big, but i can't send if it is more than 6 mb(approximately).I got this error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://example.com/uploadImage.php
```

and error at line:

```
   InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
(E/JSON Parser: Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of )
```

In my opinion, i get JSON exception because there is not answer from server. But i cant understand why i get this error.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://example.com/uploadImage.php
```

Is it possible, that server doesn`t accept incoming file more than some Mb?

**EDIT:** When i change compress ratio from 50 to 10 i can upload image that i couldn`t. So, i am sure that error occurs because of image size.

This error occurs before **`setReadTimeout`** and **`setConnectTimeout`** exceed.

my PHP codes:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST)) {


$name =$_POST["name"];
$image =$_POST["image"];

$decodedImage= base64_decode("$image");

$resultt=file_put_contents("images/" .$name. ".JPG",$decodedImage);

if($resultt){


    $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "".$resultt. "";
        die(json_encode($response));

}
    $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Fail";
        die(json_encode($response));

}



?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe problem in server.

php.ini file is inside your server.

PHP has several configuration options to limit resources consumed by scripts. By default, PHP is set to allow uploads of files with a size of 2MB or less.

Try increasing the following values in php.ini, for example:

```
memory_limit = 32M
upload_max_filesize = 24M
post_max_size = 32M
```

Comment: i will try this and write here. So, if the problem is that how can i return answer from server?I want to pass server's answer to JSON.